# perl outlook to print the last word of an email header

Tags: perl

I have a script that matches part of an email subject line, then prints the email body to an output file for sorting etc, the emails are then moved to a sub folder.
 what i would like to do is get the last word of the subject line (which is a name) and idealy add that word to the end of each line of the email body, this is what i have at present, it successfully prints the email body's to output and moves them as well.

```
<code>
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
#use diagnostics;

use Win32::OLE;
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Outlook';

my $filename = 'c:\\test.txt';
open( my $output_fh, ">", $filename ) or die $!;

my $outlook = Win32::OLE->new('Outlook.Application')
    or die "Failed Opening Outlook.";

my $namespace    = $outlook->GetNamespace("MAPI");
 my $folder = $namespace->Folders("inbox");
my $tofolder = $namespace->Folders("archive");
my $items        = $folder->Items;

foreach my $msg ( $items->in ) {
    if ( $msg->{Subject} =~ m/^test test test / ) {
    my @name = split(/ /, $msg);
        print $name[-1] . "\n";
        print {$output_fh} $msg->{Body};
        $msg->Move($tofolder );
    }
}

close($output_fh);
<code>
```

this warning appears 'Win32::OLE=HASH(0x2a9432c)'

```
<code>
 the Email subject lines will be 
 test test test micky
 test test test jony
 test test test dave
 test test test adam
so i would like the name added to each line of the email body

<code>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your split appears to be wrong.

```
my @name = split(/ /, $msg);
```

should that not be

```
my @name = split(/ /, $msg->{Subject});
```

Also, I'd be tempted to do a capture in the first subject test:

```
if ( $msg->{Subject} =~ m/^test test test (.*)/ ) {
    my $name = $1;
    print "$name\n";
```

Note also that I'm not using the . operator - it's generally considered sweeter to use expansion in double-quoted strings.